# MySQL breaking foreign keys with triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, foreign-keys

A somewhat simply question, is one allowed, to break a foreign key inside a trigger?

That is, can I break the foreign key inside my trigger function, if I restore it before returning from the trigger function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bi_example BEFORE INSERT ON example FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
  -- do stuff
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
END $$
```

Comment: Perfect! - Just what I needed!